# SBT doesn't call Test.Setup on a Play2 project

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Here is my SBT build:

```
  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(defaultScalaSettings:_*)
    .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.0",
    resolvers += .....
  )
    .configs(IntegrationTest)
    .settings( Defaults.itSettings : _*)
    .settings(
    testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup( () => println("Setup Test yoohooo") ),
    testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup( () => println("Cleanup Test yoohoo") ),
    scalaSource in Test <<= baseDirectory / "test/unit",
    parallelExecution in Test := true,

    testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Setup( () => println("Setup Integration Test yoohoo") ),
    testOptions in IntegrationTest += Tests.Cleanup( () => println("Cleanup Integration Test yoohoo") ),
    scalaSource in IntegrationTest <<= baseDirectory / "test/integration",
    parallelExecution in IntegrationTest := false

  )
```

I can launch both tasks `test` and `it:test`, but it only prints the text for the IntegrationTest, and not for the regular Test.

I see that Play2 has some default settings related:

```
testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup { loader =>
  loader.loadClass("play.api.Logger").getMethod("init", classOf[java.io.File]).invoke(null, new java.io.File("."))
},

testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup { loader =>
  loader.loadClass("play.api.Logger").getMethod("shutdown").invoke(null)
},
```

Isn't my build supposed to override these settings?

By the way, can I call an external library or a test source class in this Setup?

Comment: "By the way, can I call an external library or a test source class in this Setup?". Yes, but you have to call it reflectively, as it won't be on the classpath when compiling your build definition.

Comment: It seems a bit painful. Even for calling an external library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is constraint of sbt.

sbt official documents says

> Setup and Cleanup actions are not supported when a group is forked.

https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v0.12.2/src/sphinx/Detailed-Topics/Testing.rst#forking-tests

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html

```
fork in Test := true
```

is default from Play2.1.0

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/pull/654/files#L5L110

Comment: This limitation was lifted in sbt 0.13.0.