# SBT - Test.Setup throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

We are currently using SBT and Play to do a project.

We would like to spin upthe database and play only *ONCE* to lower the testing times.

SBT offers `Tests.Setup` and `Tests.Cleanup` to do this; http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Detailed-Topics/Testing.html

I've defined the following object in `test/util/TestServer.scala`

```
object TestServer {
  def start = println("hello")
}
```

To let this print I hook it up in the SBT config:

```
play.Project(name = appName, applicationVersion = appVersion, dependencies = appDependencies)
    .settings(
      // snip .. wiring resolvers and template/routes imports here
      testOptions in Test += Tests.Argument("junitxml", "console"),
      testOptions in Test += Tests.Setup(_.loadClass("util.TestServer$").getMethod("start").invoke(null)),
      testOptions in Test += Tests.Cleanup(_.loadClass("util.TestServer$").getMethod("stop").invoke(null)),
      scalacOptions += "-feature",
      doc in Compile
```

However when I run this, it complains about not finding the the TestServer class:

```
$ sh play.sh test
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/markdejong/Projects/malmberg-baps/project
[info] Set current project to Malmberg (in build file:/Users/markdejong/Projects/malmberg-baps/)
[info] Updating {file:/Users/markdejong/Projects/malmberg-baps/}core...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/markdejong/Projects/malmberg-baps/}macros...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for core/test:test
[info] Done updating.
[info] Updating {file:/Users/markdejong/Projects/malmberg-baps/}Malmberg...
[info] Resolving org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2 ...
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for macros/test:test
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.TestServer$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at ApplicationBuild$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Build.scala:89)
    at ApplicationBuild$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Build.scala:89)
    at sbt.ForkTests$$anonfun$sbt$ForkTests$$all$1$1.apply(ForkTests.scala:20)
    at sbt.ForkTests$$anonfun$sbt$ForkTests$$all$1$1.apply(ForkTests.scala:20)
    at sbt.std.TaskExtra$$anon$1$$anonfun$fork$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TaskExtra.scala:99)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$3$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(System.scala:45)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (Malmberg/test:executeTests) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: util.TestServer$
[error] Total time: 11 s, completed Apr 23, 2014 7:11:07 PM
```

What is the problem here?

I've also tried `util.TestServer` and util.TestServer$class, but gives the same error.

Using sbt version 0.13.0 and Play 2.2.2

Comment: which version of play2 and sbt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346140/sbt-doesnt-call-test-setup-on-a-play2-project

Comment: Using sbt 0.13.0 and Play 2.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Kenji Yoshida I found the problem.

It was indeed the "fork" mode introduced by the Play Framework. You have to set it to false in order to make it work with these versions.